# Why does MySQL order by random_bytes have no effect?

Tags: mysql

`order by random_bytes(8)` has no effect.  Why?

Using MySQL (on AWS serverless v2)

Consider this testing procedure:

```
create procedure Test()
begin

    create temporary table Meow (Id bigint);
    insert into Meow (Id) values (1);
    insert into Meow (Id) values (2);
    insert into Meow (Id) values (3);
    insert into Meow (Id) values (4);
    insert into Meow (Id) values (5);

    select * from Meow order by random_bytes(8);
   
    drop temporary table Meow;

end
```

Executing it always yields: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

So I tried other select statements... First, extracting it into a subquery:

```
    select * from 
    (
        select *, random_bytes(8) rnd from Meow
    ) a order by rnd;
```

But the results are still 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  Actual output:

```
    [
      { Id: 1, rnd: <Buffer 3a 9d 00 9e b7 c5 80 91> },
      { Id: 2, rnd: <Buffer a0 5e 33 da 0c c0 5c 80> },
      { Id: 3, rnd: <Buffer 1a f0 78 84 85 29 a3 22> },
      { Id: 4, rnd: <Buffer 77 f0 be 54 37 44 94 15> },
      { Id: 5, rnd: <Buffer c3 cc c1 2d 79 2b f3 df> }
    ]
```

Then I suspected maybe it doesn't like working with bytes, so I tried with a string:

```
    select * from 
    (
        select *, hex(random_bytes(8)) rnd from Meow
    ) a order by rnd;
```

But again, it's always 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  Actual output:

```
    [
      { Id: 1, rnd: '8896C5F824A86BCF' },
      { Id: 2, rnd: '42C16697444537C6' },
      { Id: 3, rnd: '538D11E7FDA91D10' },
      { Id: 4, rnd: '09F3069EF0A36E6C' },
      { Id: 5, rnd: '706DEC985E298FA5' }
    ]
```

Why?

PS:  I did test with `order by Id desc`, and THAT returns 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

EDIT (answering comment Q's):  `select Version()` = 8.0.23 ... and table vs temporary table makes no difference.

ANSWER:  It's an optimizer bug, verified by the mysql team.  Bug filed at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=111252

UPDATE:  Fixed in 8.0.34 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-34.html

Comment: Why use `random_bytes(8)` instead of `rand()`?

Comment: The strange thing is that `ORDER BY rnd DESC` also returns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. It seems to be ignoring it.

Comment: Unless we're missing something, this looks like a bug.  Maybe RDS applies a bad optimization for temporary tables?  What happens if you do this in 2 steps, create table, select, without it being a temp table?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: I can reproduce this result on my local MySQL 8.0 instance on my laptop, so it's not just an RDS bug. But if I use `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...` to save the result of the `random_bytes()` query, then I can query that table with an ORDER BY and it sorts as expected. It's as if the `random_bytes()` isn't generated until after the sorting happens, so all those rows are tied, and it defaults to the order of the index read. I have no explanation for this, but just wanted to say I confirm I see the same behavior.

Comment: `ORDER BY random_bytes()` will generate the random bytes once, I believe, so it's like `ORDER BY <nothing>` in its effect. You might consider looking into seeded randomization if you want random results but consistent between requests for something like pagination.

Comment: Thanks.  But no, it *should* work.  It's now a bug verified by the mysql team.  Link at bottom of post.

Comment: @ceejayoz That doesn't explain why it fails with the subquery. The output shows that it's a different set of random bytes in each row.